# why is this for loop prepending numbers?

Tags: php

In this example, why is my output `321_content`? Shouldn't it be `_contenet`? doesn't the loop overwrite the `$string` variable on each iteration, leaving me with `4_content` before the `substr` and `_content` after the `substr` is applied?

```
<?php

$string = "_content";

for ($x=1; $x<5; $x++){
    $string = $x . $string;
}

$string = substr($string,1);

echo $string;
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: if $string = _content, then you do this  $string = $x . $string; then $string will be "1_content" after the first loop.

Comment: Read my question. It clearly states my expected result.

Comment: on the 2nd loop, it will be 21_string... and so on

Comment: and after doing substr then it will just remove 4 from "4321_content" so what you're getting now is correct.

Comment: You must assign to different variable not to $string inside the loop if your expected result is _content after substr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you overwrite $string, but the new value also contains $string. The new value of $string becomes $x plus the previous value of string. So on each iteration an extra number is prepended.

It has to do with the order in which this code is processed. In an assignment like this, first the result of the expression (in this case `$x . $string`) is calculated. After that, the result of the expression is assigned to the variable, $string again.

So, after the first iteration, $string became '1_content', then '21_content', and so on.

You would get the result you expected only when you put the assignment into another variable:

```
<?php

$postfix = "_content";

for ($x=1; $x<5; $x++){
    $string = $x . $postfix;
}

echo $string;
```

In this code, on each iteration, $string gets a value from $x and $postfix. On each iteration this value is overwritten. $postfix remains unmodified and $string is overwritten on each iteration, so now at the end, $string contains '4_content' instead of '4321_content'.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha. I was confusing myself. In the loop, `$string` gets a new value, then on the next pass, it's used and assigned a new value. I see it now. Thanks!